# Why is Google Cloud Builder not running docker-compose up correctly?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-build

After testing that my website can successfully be deployed locally with docker, I'm trying to run a docker container directly on my GCP virtual instance. Inside my cloudbuilder.yaml file is the following:

```
steps:
  # running docker-compose
  - name: 'docker/compose:1.26.2'
    args: ['up', '--build']
    timeout: '1600s'
```

In running `gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml --timeout=1h`, I get the following error at the end of it:

```
ERROR
Creating jkl-api ... done

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "docker/compose:1.26.2" failed: context deadline exceeded
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 9712fc75-9b47-43a7-a84d-a208897fe00d completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Edit:
As per @Samantha Létourneau's comment, I decided I want to instead directly build the images for my project then run them instead of using docker-compose. I was able to successfully build and push a docker image to the Container Registry with this cloudbuilder.yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/lawma-project-356604/lawma-image', '.']
  # Docker Push
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 
          'gcr.io/lawma-project-356604/lawma-image']
```

But when i try and deploy a container i get the following error:

```
Cloud Run error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=80 environment variable.
```

and this error [1]:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "lawma-api" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:20
```

heres my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }

    location /static {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://lawma-api:8000;
    }
}
```

and my Dockerfile:

```
#Build step #1: build the React frontend
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY lawmaapp/package.json ./
COPY lawmaapp/public ./public
COPY lawmaapp/src ./src
EXPOSE 80
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

#Build step #2: build an nginx container \
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Why am i getting the error [1]?

Comment: forget about it. As far as I know, you have to decompose your docker compose and publish everything individually on google cloud.

Comment: `host not found in upstream "lawma-api"` - this is due to the fact that nginx cannot resolve the hostname `lawma-api`

Comment: @mhanna112, does the comment above answer your question? Also, have you tried this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start) to troubleshoot your error message?